# Is it possible to create a Windows 8 Store App from Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-store-apps, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

So, I have a Windows 8.1 machine with Visual Studio 2013 installed. Whenever I go to create a new Windows Store project I do not see any options to create a new Windows 8 Store app, rather than Windows 8.1 Store App. However, I have no problem opening existing Windows 8 Store App Projects.

Is it possible to create a Windows 8 Store App project from Visual Studio 2013 when running on Windows 8.1?

Comment: What version of VS are you using? Express? Ultimate?

Comment: That was never possible before, the update didn't change that :)

Comment: Knowing the price of two Visual Studio products, and considering VS2013 Update 2 new "Universal App" feature, best answer is Filip Skakun's one.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's easy - create a new 8.1 project and remove the following lines from the .csproj file:

```
<TargetPlatformVersion>8.1</TargetPlatformVersion>
<MinimumVisualStudioVersion>12</MinimumVisualStudioVersion>
```

Reopen the file and voila - it's a Windows 8 project!

Additionally, you might want to change the following as well:
In MainPage.xaml:

```
-    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
+    <Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
```

In Package.appxmanifest:

```
- <m2:VisualElements
+ <VisualElements
- Square150x150Logo="Assets\Logo.png"
- Square30x30Logo="Assets\SmallLogo.png"
+ Logo="Assets\Logo.png"
+ SmallLogo="Assets\SmallLogo.png"
- <m2:SplashScreen Image="Assets\SplashScreen.png" />
+ <SplashScreen Image="Assets\SplashScreen.png" />
- </m2:VisualElements>
+ </VisualElements>
```

If this doesn't work - it might mean that the project files have further changed in current versions of VS and you might need to install VS 2012 (Express should do) and create a project in that. You can then work on it in the new version of VS.

Comment: Will it still run on Windows 8.1 along with windows 8?

Comment: Any app built for Windows 8 should run on Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to create a Windows 8 Store App project from Visual Studio 2013 when running on Windows 8.1?

No.  You need to use Visual Studio 2012 to create the Windows 8 project, then open it in VS 2013.  This can be done in Windows 8.1, but requires installing VS 2012 side by side with VS 2013.

Comment: And so would that also mean that VS2013 on Windows 8 can only create Windows 8.1 store apps?

Comment: @Earlz Nope - you can't develop for Windows 8.1 on Windows 8... need to upgrade if you want to do store apps using VS 2013 (unless you create on VS 2012 in Win8, then open in VS 2013, and leave it targetting 8)

Comment: @Earlz In general, it's a bit of a mess (in my humble opinion)

Comment: I tend to agree. It reminds me of the really old versions of Visual Studio where you couldn't target different versions of .Net. ugh

Comment: Why have we gone from Visual Studio versions that could build for all kinds of platforms to one version per platform? If Microsoft keeps up with 1 version of Visual Studio per year, developers are going to have to install tons of giant IDEs side-by-side just to keep up.

Comment: @JustinSkiles This has always been the case in the C++ realm - each version only targets that compiler chain.  The managed languages have been spoiled here, but it looks like targeting Windows Store, at least for now, is more like native dev...

Comment: Could be much worse.. every time I plug in my iPod, to run a test build, XCode doesn't recognize it and I have to do an XCode upgrade.  Seriously, upgraded to iOS 8.0, had to upgrade XCode.  Upgraded to iOS 8.0.1, had to upgrade XCode again, upgraded to 8.0.2, had to upgrade XCode again.

Answer (score 2):

I did the following:

It's easy - create a new 8.1 project and remove the following lines from the .csproj file:

```
<TargetPlatformVersion>8.1</TargetPlatformVersion>
<MinimumVisualStudioVersion>12</MinimumVisualStudioVersion>
```

Reopen the file and voila - it's a Windows 8 project!

But it's not Voila.  Reloading the project after this edit puts up a dialog saying VS2013 needs an update, and directs you to the MS Download site (assumedly to download the Phone 8.0 SDK.

I made completely sure I had the Phone 8.0 SDK installed with VS2013 installer.  I even went so far as to remove (with 2013 installer) and re-add.  Still this behavior persists.  I'm now downloading the 8.0 SDK, which is installing 2012 Express of course.  We'll see if that helps, but it seems like this shouldn't be necessary.  What am I missing?

It didn't resolve the behavior.  Now, I load up the solution and it won't load the project.  The project has the notation (update required).  When you select download update from the context menu, it just takes you to MS Downloads--no idea what needs to be downloaded.

Can someone please explain the highly voted answer above?  I'm running Win 8.1 Pro with VS2013 Premium (Phone 8 SDK installed)...and I now have the VS2012 Express install that came with the regular Phone 8.0 SDK download.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it tries to take you to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?prd=12514&pver=12.0&sbp=PlatformSDKMissing&plcid=0x409&o1=WindowsPhoneApp,%20Version=8.0 but that link appears broken.

Comment: It doesn't seem like you have answered the question here though you bring valid points. Use comments next time. It's possible the later updates to Visual Studio 2013 have changed more things in the projects and more updates are necessary than mentioned in my answer. Someone should do a diff on the two projects (one from VS 2012 and one from the current version) and update the answer. A better option might be to share an updated project template. I wonder if you could just copy it from the VS 2012 install... Otherwise - creating the project with VS 2012 Express might be the solution.

Answer (score 1):

As Reed said, you cannot create Windows 8 App store project in Visual Studio 2013 and you need to have VS2012 installed too. But as a trick you can make a copy from an existing Win 8 app project and modify it. It is not very neat solution but works if you do not want to install VS2012 as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Visual Studio 2012 to create the Windows 8 projects.

Based on my own experience if you don't have do developer a Windows 8 version, just focus on 8.1. For me only 3% of the sales are generated by the Windows 8 version. I only backported my 8.1 app for experience sake.

Comment: 19 % of my customers are using WP7 :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot developer Windows 8.0 application using VS 2013. You have to install VS 2012 for Windows 8.0.