# How to Remote Debug on a Tablet with Windows 8 using a project on my PC that runs Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

I want to Remotely Debug a Windows Store Application on a tablet which has Windows 8 and Visual Studio Remote Debugger 2013 installed.

The Windows Store App is on my PC with Windows 8.1 installed and when I try to debug I get the following error:

```
Error : DEP0700 : Registration of the app failed. error 0xC00CE014:           App manifest     validation error: The app manifest must be valid as per schema: Line 25, Column    8, Reason: Element '{http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2013/manifest}VisualElements' is unexpected according to content model of parent element '{http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2010/manifest}Application'.
Expecting: {http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2010/manifest}VisualElements.
 (0x80080204)   TabletDemo
```

Is there any way around this without upgrading my Tablet to Windows 8.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio 2013 targets Windows 8.1. You need to use Visual Studio 2012 to target Windows 8.

But you can also have a look to this post : [Is it possible to create a Windows 8 Store App from Visual Studio 2013?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19413073/is-it-possible-to-create-a-windows-8-store-app-from-visual-studio-2013)

By manually modifying the .csproj file it seems possible to use 2013 to target 8.0. Remove the lines :

```
<TargetPlatformVersion>8.1</TargetPlatformVersion>
<MinimumVisualStudioVersion>12</MinimumVisualStudioVersion>
```

Comment: I tried changing 8.1 to 8 but the project fails when I open it

Comment: You have to remove the lines <TargetPlatformVertion> and <MinimumVisualStudioVersion>

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution from a previous question:

[Is it possible to create a Windows 8 Store App from Visual Studio 2013?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19413073/is-it-possible-to-create-a-windows-8-store-app-from-visual-studio-2013)

Here are the steps:

Go to your project folder and edit your project's .csproj file:

- Uncomment or delete the elements:

  *< TargetPlatformVersion > 8.1 < /TargetPlatformVersion >*

  ***and***

  *< MinimumVisualStudioVersion > 12 < /MinimumVisualStudioVersion >*
- Open your project in Visual Studio
- Open your MainPage.xaml file:

  **Change** < Grid Background="{**ThemeResource** ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

  **to**

  < Grid Background="{**StaticResource** ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

  **and**

  **Delete** Style="{StaticResource NavigationBackButtonNormalStyle}"

  **and**

  **Delete** Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}"
- Open your Package.appxmanifest file's code definition and change:

  < **m2**:VisualElements
              DisplayName="App2"
              Square150x150Logo="Assets\Logo.png"
              Square30x30Logo="Assets\SmallLogo.png"
              Description="App2"
              ForegroundText="light"
              BackgroundColor="#464646">
              < **m2**:SplashScreen Image="Assets\SplashScreen.png" />
   < /**m2**:VisualElements>

  ***to***

  < VisualElements 
          DisplayName="TabletDemo" 
          Logo="Assets\Logo.png" 
          SmallLogo="Assets\SmallLogo.png" 
          Description="TabletDemo" 
          ForegroundText="light" 
          BackgroundColor="#464646">
      < DefaultTile ShortName="aa">
      < /DefaultTile>
      < SplashScreen Image="Assets\SplashScreen.png" />
    < /VisualElements>

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the `<TargetPlatformVersion>` and `<MinimumVisualStudioVersion>` tags from the .csproj file.

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19413073/is-it-possible-to-create-a-windows-8-store-app-from-visual-studio-2013)

Answer (score 0):

changed

8.1
to 
8.0 in **TargetPlatformVersion** in the project's .csproj file

And

< m2:VisualElements DisplayName="App2" Square150x150Logo="Assets\Logo.png" Square30x30Logo="Assets\SmallLogo.png" Description="App2" ForegroundText="light" BackgroundColor="#464646"> < m2:SplashScreen Image="Assets\SplashScreen.png" /> < /m2:VisualElements>

to

< VisualElements DisplayName="TabletDemo" Logo="Assets\Logo.png" SmallLogo="Assets\SmallLogo.png" Description="TabletDemo" ForegroundText="light" BackgroundColor="#464646"> < DefaultTile ShortName="aa"> < /DefaultTile> < SplashScreen Image="Assets\SplashScreen.png" /> < /VisualElements>  in Package.appxmanifest file.

These 2 changes fixed the issue for me