# Metro App - re-targeting version from 8.1 to 8

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am building app for Windows Store.

If I target my app to Windows 8,
will it be able to run under Win 8.1 ?
If yes , then how can I re-target existing app from 8.1 to 8 ?

Comment: yes, Apps for 8 work in 8 and 8.1. Which VS version do you use?

Comment: I use VS2013. Can I deploy only one version of app to Windows Store then ?

Comment: If you only have a Windows 8 app, both Windows 8 and 8.1 users will be able to run your app. On the other hand, if you upload only a 8.1 app, only 8.1 users will see the app from the app store.

The other question on how to re-target existing app from 8.1 to 8, there are no easy way as it's highly likely that you've used some 8.1-only features. The most straightforward way is to open up the project file in a text editor and change the version to 8 manually.

Comment: [I found this solution that works for me][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19413073/is-it-possible-to-create-a-windows-8-store-app-from-visual-studio-2013