# Updating Windows 8 app. Possible?

Tags: c#, windows-8, visual-studio-2015, windows-8.1

I have a Windows 8 app that needs an update. However, when I load the app in Visual Studio 2015 it's requiring me to retarget the project to Windows 8.1. Is it possible to still update Windows 8 apps? If so, how?

[image]

Comment: fyi windows 8 is leaving standard support soon.

Comment: Not possible with VS2015, you will need to keep your VS2012 installation and project files if you want to support Windows 8.

Comment: thanks, i'll try that. (if it works, you should write up your comment as an answer.)

Comment: i was able to download visual studio 2012. but it requires a key and i can't buy one... any ideas?

Comment: [VS2013 supports Win 8.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19413073/is-it-possible-to-create-a-windows-8-store-app-from-visual-studio-2013). There is a community edition, you may want to see if you can download a copy.

Comment: As Daniel said, Win8 support has ended this month, so it makes no sense to support the app any longer. Retarget the app to 8.1 and support the 8.1 version

Comment: @magicandre1981 we have 1000s of users on the windows 8 platform who haven't upgraded yet. so i need to update the windows 8 version of the app, not create a windows 8.1 update.

Comment: tell them to do. Win8 is now dead and they run into security issue